# ReadResponse() failed: When uploading large amounts of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I came across an issue today when adding an upload data modification to a ASP.NET 3.5 C# Web App. The user needs to upload a spreadsheet with a .xls extension containing large amounts of data. That spreadsheet will be converted to a datatable and then inserted into SQL Via a SqlBulkInsert method. The problem I am having is the sheet I am currently working with has 16 columns and can only contain 24889 rows before I receive this message from the server via Fiddler, 'ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.' I've searched and not found much info on this related to my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try giving some values for maxRequestLength like below

```
<system.web>
    <!-- ... -->

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800"/>

    <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
```

Comment: I already had that size increased but I uped it to 1000000 and it didn't help. Also I think I was too early on the .csv comment. I went back to increase the data again and I got the same failure.

Comment: @Tim, Consider edit your question that with this findings... Also make sure that there is no other web.config file that impacts subset of the site that handles your upload.

Answer (score 1):

By default you can upload a file upto 4MB.

The size of your excel must be excedding the limit.

What you can do is set the setting in Web Configuration file

What this will do is increase the request size that server can respond to.

Comment: I thought the default limit was 30mbs the file definitely exceeds 4mb I am currently running with this entry in my web.config <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>

Comment: by default the limit is only 4MB. for more size you need to set the request length size in web.config. (<httpRunTime maxRequestLength="size in bytes" />)

Comment: the setting you are using is for maximum limit of connections to server. More on that here http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits .

Comment: thanks DnshPly9 and Pankaj maxRequestLength was the solution. I thought I already put that one in there but it was <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20001" /> that I put in for another data reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into server logs to figure out what cases it (or simply debug the server portion if you can). You also should see if it cased by simply size of the file or data in the file (if you do any processing).

Possible reasons:

- you code gets the data, but fails in some way likely tearing down whole process
- ASP.Net blocks request due to size (see Pankaj Garg answer).
- your code is just too slow

Comment: the base class is never called so it does not even reach my code. The server is rejecting the file before it makes it to the code.